# Problem with cygnetcdf-13.dll needed to use new versions of CDO with Cygwin

Tags: windows, dll, cygwin, cdo-climate

I have problems with the use of newest version CDO, like CDO-1.9.7.1.
This appears when I try tu use any CDO operator with Cygwin in windows 10:
"error while loading shared libraries: cygnetcdf-13.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I have no problems with older versions of CDO (<= CDO-1.9.5).

Does anyone knows how to fix it and use the new versions of CDO in windows 10 with Cygwin, or other shell option in Windows?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I were you, I would switch from cygwin to installing the ubuntu subsystem under windows.  Then you can simply use apt-get to manage software. I find it more robust and software is much more up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cygcheck to find the proper package:

```
$ cygcheck -p cygnetcdf-13.dll
Found 4 matches for cygnetcdf-13.dll
libnetcdf13-4.6.0-1 - libnetcdf13: NetCDF (network Common Data Form)
libnetcdf13-4.6.1-1 - libnetcdf13: NetCDF (network Common Data Form)
libnetcdf13-4.6.1-2 - libnetcdf13: NetCDF (network Common Data Form)
netcdf-debuginfo-4.6.1-2 - netcdf-debuginfo: Debug info for netcdf
```

so you need to install the `libnetcdf13` package.

If you need to look which programs are needed for it, there is
a proper line in

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libnetcdf13.html

`depends: cygwin, libcurl4, libgcc1 (x86), libhdf5_101, libhdf5hl_100`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I had to install all the necessary packages through Cygwin's setup.exe. That is to say, every time a warning appears like "error while loading shared libraries:  .dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" it should be looked for in setup.exe. If you can't find it, I recommend searching the web for the specific .dll and downloading it from the internet, to save it in the bin folder, for example: C: \ cygwin64 \ bin
Additionally, the cygeccodes.dll file (which comes with the CDO installer) must be moved to the same bin folder.
If there is a missing .dll associated with HDF5, I recommend installing all the packages that include that acronym in setup.exe, example: libhdf5_101
With this I was able to get all current versions of CDO working in Cygwin. After 3 days of looking for solutions, I am happy to have achieved it! I hope this helps you! :)